# Interested in visiting Uzbekistan

Tags: visas, transit-visas, us-citizens, uzbekistan

I am an American citizen interested in visiting Uzbekistan this summer. I have several questions.

1) If I am visiting for just a short period of time (3 days) for the exclusive purpose of visiting a friend, do I need a visa? If so, is a tourist visa sufficient or do I need a private visitor visa?

2) If I go for a longer period of time and cross the land border to visit Afghanistan, what visa do I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Uzbekistan.html you need a Private Visa to stay with a friend in Uzbekistan.

You also need a visa to enter Afghanistan, however the current travel advisory is Level 4: Do not travel https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Afghanistan.html

Comment: Uzbekistan issues e-visas that are easy to get.